# Magento 2 remove zoom/full screen image link

Tags: magento2, zoom

We have a Magento 2.1 based website we want to remove the image zoon feature on the product detail page. we were able to get the magnifying glass removed from the image but can not figure out how to actually remove the ability to click on the image and have it open full screen.

In the Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml we added

```
<remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/jquery.zoom.min.js" />
```

However that doesnt do the trick because you can still click on the image and it opens in a full screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/[theme]/[theme]/etc/view.xml

**Search for:**

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">true</var>
```

**change it to:**

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
```

And then clear the cache in the backend. Np compiling or deploying needed.