# How to disable fotoroma fullscreen image gallery?

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

[image]

I want to disable fotoroma fullscreen image and I did that by disabling the fullscreen in `view.xml` in the theme but it doesn't make any effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the code how you did ? Also did you try to delete cache ?

Comment: Please refer here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206446/magento-2-remove-zoom-full-screen-image-link

Comment: i have modify the allfullscreen true to false in view.xml file in the